# Roland ACH power supply connector identification

Tags: connector, identification

Can anyone please identify this connector, as used for the output of the ±10 VDC "ACH" series power supply for a Roland R-8 drum machine from the late '80s?

The male socket into which this fits has internal measurements of about 18.0mm x 9.5mm.

Annoyingly the female pins are larger than the "standard" 0.093" Molex connector pins that you'd find in e.g. a hard drive power connector.

[image]

(I don't have this plug, this is a photo found online)

Comment: Is this on the AC side or the DC side of the supply?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's on the DC side - question clarified accordingly.